# (Objective C) When I make a new instance of a class inheriting from UIView using initWithFrame, why is the position not showing correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame, cgrect

In my appdelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 150);

OtherView *newView = [[OtherView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
//UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];

newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.window addSubview:newView];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

OtherView is simply a blank class that inherits from UIView.

When I use the commented out code instead of Otherview, my CGRect is in the correct position, but when I use the code above as is, my CGRect is off-screen on the top left.

Comment: Show header file OtherView.h i test ur code and it work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try clean project `CMD+SHIFT+K`, you have not import OtherView.h or wrong inherits UIView

Comment: found the problem! OtherView.h has a frame property that was overriding the parent frame property. Thanks for your help